# raspistill won't work when automating shots on 1GB PI 4

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, pi-4

THIS WORKS:

```
raspistill -cs 0 -ISO 600 -ss 175000 -w 1920 -h 1080 -o watcher-0000.jpg
```

This does not

```
raspistill -cs 0 -t 46800000 -ISO 600 -ss 175000 -w 1920 -h 1080 -o watcher-%04d.jpg
```

I have tried with and without the `-cs 0`. As can be seen the only difference is the `-t` and auto-naming of the jpegs.

It worked a couple times, and now just stopped.  I have rebooted, cold booted and cussed at it*.

I am using a 3A PI supply.   I think I can rule out hardware since single shots work every time.    I have tried using `-t 0`, and executing the command with `sudo`.

It does work.  Apparently I was not waiting long enough for it to start working.  After entering this question.  I looked once more, and it's working.  Arrrrrrrrrrrrrrrgh!  It was over a minute before it started to run

Comment: Consider posting your edit as a self-answer.